# How to match non-Unicode string with regexp in Ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby, ascii

I wanna to match string that contain `\xa0`, Like:

```
"\xa0" =~ /\xa0/
```

But error will throw with:

```
SyntaxError: (eval):2: invalid multibyte escape: /\xa0/
```

I am try to use Unicode to match:

```
"\xa0" =~ /\u00a0/
```

error will throw too:

```
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

So, how to match \xa0 in ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every byte sequence is a valid Unicode string. (or more specifically UTF-8)

Your single-byte string for example is not:

```
str = "\xa0"

str.encoding        #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
str.valid_encoding? #=> false
str.codepoints      #   ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)
```

To work with an arbitrary string, you have set its encoding to [binary](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-b) / ASCII:

```
str = "\xa0".b      # <-- note the .b

str.encoding        #=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
str.valid_encoding? #=> true
str.codepoints      #=> [160]
```

and also set the [regexp encoding](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Encoding) to ASCII: (via the `n` modifier)

```
str =~ /\xa0/n
#=> 0
```

Comment: @TangMonk because the byte 0x01 is a valid codepoint in Unicode.